# Как сделать защиту от ввода неверного ответа (защита от дурака)

Tags: python

```
otv = input('1.Побежать на опережение\n2.Спокойно дойти до остановки.')
if otv == '1':
    print('Вы догнали автобус')
    print('Наконец,ты подъехала к зданию университета и ахнула')
    print('Хелена:\nВот это красота!')
    print('Хелена:\nА этот дизайн!')
    print('Впрочем ты оказалась невнимательна и врезалась в парняс книгами.Ты осмотрела его и сказала:')
if otv == '2':
    print('Ты решила не играть в догонялки с автобусом и потратила время на то,чтобы дождаться следующего')
    print('Наконец,ты подъехала к зданию университета и ахнула')
    print('Хелена:\nВот это красота!')
    print('Хелена:\nА этот дизайн!')
    print('Впрочем ты оказалась невнимательна и врезалась в парня с книгами.Ты осмотрела его и сказала:')
```

что то по типу этого только надо вставить это в код выше

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(raw_input("Введите число: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Вы должны ввести число, попробуйте снова."
main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если заранее знаем, что нужно вот конкретно для этой задачи получать только натуральные числа, можно около того:

```
def user_option(messages: list):
    msg = '\n'.join(messages); qty = len(messages)

    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(msg))
            if not val in range(1, qty + 1):
                raise ValueError
            return val

        except ValueError:
            print('Вводите только числа от 1 до', qty)


val = user_option([
    '1. Побежать на опережение',
    '2. Спокойно дойти до остановки'
])

if val == 1:
    print('1')
elif val == 2:
    print('2')
```

В цикле будет повторять запрос до тех пор, пока не введут 1 или 2.

Можете попробовать написать функцию, принимающую произвольное количество аргументов вместо списка. [*args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

Вот один из путей решения:

```
while True:
    try:
        otv = int(input('1.Побежать на опережение\n2.Спокойно дойти до остановки.'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Вы должны ввести число, попробуйте снова.")
if otv == 1:
    print('Вы догнали автобус')
    print('Наконец,ты подъехала к зданию университета и ахнула')
    print('Хелена:\nВот это красота!')
    print('Хелена:\nА этот дизайн!')
    print('Впрочем ты оказалась невнимательна и врезалась в парняс книгами.Ты осмотрела его и сказала:')
if otv == 2:
    print('Ты решила не играть в догонялки с автобусом и потратила время на то,чтобы дождаться следующего')
    print('Наконец,ты подъехала к зданию университета и ахнула')
    print('Хелена:\nВот это красота!')
    print('Хелена:\nА этот дизайн!')
    print('Впрочем ты оказалась невнимательна и врезалась в парня с книгами.Ты осмотрела его и сказала:')
```